# Bot only finding me and bot in guild members? (Discord.js V13)

Tags: discord.js

Alright, so, I made a simple button system and I added this bit of code:

```
bot.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
 interaction.guild.members.cache.forEach(m => {
    console.log(m.user.username)
 });
});
```

And whenever I check my console, it only prints two usernames, me and my bot's name. Why isn't it printing every single user inside of the guild's names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cache` will return only the cached members in the guild, hence it's name. You'll want to fetch the members first.

```js
bot.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
 const allMembers = await interaction.guild.members.fetch();
 allMembers.forEach(m => {
    console.log(m.user.username);
 });
});
```

Ensure you have the Guild Member's intent enabled